# how to add key value pairs to object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `dates` array, and I am trying to create an object with key/value pairs.  Month name will be the key, and date will be the value.

In below code, it's printing an empty object. Any idea what is missing to achieve:

```
{
  'may': ['2018/05/24', '2018/05/30']
}
```

main.ts

```
const arr = ["2018/05/24","2018/05/30"]    
private buildObject(obj) {
        const _obj = obj;
        let dateObject = {};
        _obj.forEach((element) => {
            const d = new Date(element);
            const m = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
            for (const key in dateObject){

                if (_obj) {
                    dateObject[key] = Object.assign({}, {[m]: element});
                }
            }

        })

        console.log("____DATES", dateObject);
        return dateObject;
    }

console.log(this.buildObject(arr));
```

Comment: `_obj.forEach(element => {const d = new Date(element); dataObject[monthNames[d.getMonth()]] = d; })`. You are getting an empty object because the loop `for (const key in dateObject)` never executes. `dateObject` doesn't have an properties so there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: `Object['THEY KEY YOU WANT TO ADD'] = [THE VALUE]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is all sorts of wrong.

- The loop will never execute because your object is empty.
- The `if` statement is unnecessary because `_obj` is always an array.
- List item `Object.assign({}, {[m]: element});` unnecessarily merges a new object into an empty object. It is is the same as just writing `{[m]: element}`.

Since you don't explain what the output should be, I can only assume that you want to map month names to a *list* of dates. The following code does that:

```js
const monthNames = {4: "May"};
const arr = ["2018/05/24","2018/05/30"];
const dateObject = {};

for (const dateString of arr) {
  const date = new Date(dateString);
  const month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
  if (dateObject[month]) {
    dateObject[month].push(dateString);
  } else {
    dateObject[month] = [dateString];
  }
}
console.log(dateObject);
```

---

Generalized "group by" function:

```
function groupBy(arr, keyFunc) {
  const result = {};
  for (const value of arr) {
    const key = keyFunc(value);
    if (result[key]) {
      result[key].push(value);
    } else {
      result[key] = [value];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

used as

```
const dateObject = groupBy(
  arr,
  dateString => monthNames[new Date(dateString).getMonth()],
);
```

Comment: sorry it might be silly question but what you are doing here in if statement did not understand its not declared yet `if(dateObject[month])`

Comment: I'm checking whether `dateObject[month]` has a value (an array). If it does I am appending the date to the existing array (`.push`).  If it does not I am creating the array and assign it to the property (`= [date]`).

Comment: Thank you thats what i wanted to achieve i have multiple dates for each month so that gives expected output.

Comment: FYI, this procedure is called "group by". You are *grouping* values *by* some criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to loop through the array that is passed in.

```js
const arr = ["2018/05/24","2018/05/30"]    
function buildObject(obj) {
        
        let dateObject = {};
        obj.forEach(function(element) {
            let d = new Date(element);
            let mounth =  d.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
            dateObject[mounth] ? dateObject[mounth].push(element) :dateObject[mounth]= [element];
        })  
        return dateObject;
    }
console.log(buildObject(arr));
```